# Margin in absolute position <ul> of a menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with margin-top and margin-left of 12 pixels for the elements  that are inside another , but when the cursor is between that space (margin), the menu is hidden. I can solve that if I remove position:absolute, but I need it. How can I solve this?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Food</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Chilean food</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Chinese food</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mexican food</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Nachos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quesadillas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tacos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li ul li ul {
    top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3ebd6hy/3/

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you remove your first sub-menu's margin-top and you second sub-menu's margin-left? Works fine if they are removed

Answer (score 0):

Change the `margin-top` to `padding-top` in `ul li ul`.

[Fiddle for Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/ecdyhbkp/2/)